# Excluding a dep from react native bundle

Tags: react-native, webpack, bundling-and-minification

I'm using react native 0.54.0, trying to bundle a dependency which relies on some node core apis (`net`, `fs`, `tls`), but those are required only for part of functionality which is not gonna be used on the client. I've successfully bundled that dep for web client by specifying those node core modules as externals for webpack, making it omit them from bundling. Now I'm trying to do the same for metro bundler.
I'm trying to config `rn-cli.config.js` to handle that with `getBlacklistRE`:

```
  const blacklist = require('metro/src/blacklist');

  getBlacklistRE() {
    return blacklist([
      /^morgan$/,
      /^superagent-proxy$/,
      /^fs$/,
      /^net$/,
      /^tls$/
    ]);
```

but it doesn't seem to work, I still get bundling errors about being unable to locate those modules. What am I doing wrong? How can I make the metro bundler omit those?